# Sectarianism within Hinduism

Tags: vaishnavism, shaivism

To what extent are Hindus sectarian?  For example, do most Hindus belong to a sect, e.g. Shaivism or Vaishnavism?  Do they only go to temples within their sect?  Does the entire family belong to the same sect?  Are marriages arranged only within that sect?  Are there many families that have been part of that sect for many centuries?  Are children's names picked according to the sect?

I had thought that most Hindus were not sectarian, but then I saw a post or two that led me to think otherwise.

Comment: Quite a bit, Yes with more sects within Shaivism and Vaishnavism, Not always, Most of them, As much as possible, Yes, Mostly Yes.

Comment: @user1952500 If you make this an answer, I think I would accept it.

Comment: this is my own anecdotal observation. The proper answer should have some amount of statistical reference or some other form of reference. Hence it's only a comment.

Comment: @user1952500 I was not expecting statistical references.  But stack's criteria may be stricter than my own on the matter.